# Invalid value for field(s) : field ID after moving the installation

Tags: custom-fields, error, installation, civicrm-home

I copied my CiviCRM installation into another machine. I imported all my old data successfully. I am able to see the old data in matching fields including data in custom fields.

I tried importing new set of data into the new machine. I am facing the error "Invalid value for field(s): field ID;"

Then I tried the same sheet on my old machine, where it works fine. My guess is it is something to do with custom fields.

Civicrm version :4.7.22
CMS : Wordpress 4.8.4 (old) 4.9.1 (new)
OS :  Windows 7 (old) Windows 10 (new)

Comment: How are you importing new data? Are you using the import feature in CiviCRM or doing something else?

Comment: yes.. import contacts in Civicrm